# R: Capture prespecified arguments of a function call

Tags: r, metaprogramming, rlang

I need to capture the prespecified arguments of a function call. This seems easy for the unspecified ones via `rlang::list2(...)`, but more difficult for the specified ones ("specified" meaning defined in the formals of the function).

I have experimented with `base::match.call` and the functions from https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/index.html#section-calls, but haven't yet been successful.

```r
library(rlang)

capture_dots <- function(..., arg1) {
  list2(...)
}

capture_dots("abc", arg1 = 1, arg2 = 2)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "abc"
#> 
#> $arg2
#> [1] 2
```

#### Desired output

```r
capture_prespecified("abc", arg1 = 1, arg2 = 2)
#> $arg1
#> [1] 1
```

Comment: Is this some situation where you don't know the names of the specified arguments?

Comment: Good point, actually I do. I want the prespecified arguments to be collected in a list. But this needs to be done in a "lazy" fashion, so that only those prespecified arguments that were provided will be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to capture all the named parameter to your function, you can use `formals()` to get their names (and just filter out the "...")

```
capture_dots <- function(..., arg1) {
  args <- Filter(function(x) x!="...", names(formals()))
  as.list(environment())[args]
}

capture_dots("abc", arg1 = 1, arg2 = 2)
```

Or, if you run it early in the function, the dots wont expand and there won't be any other variables so you can just grab the current environment with

```
capture_dots <- function(..., arg1) {
  as.list(environment())
}
```

Comment: This answer works. If no answer based on rlang comes up, I will accept it.

Comment: so i have this code now (in a function factory), which will get the named arguments of the created functionat "runtime": caller_env(0) %>% as.list() %>% Filter(function(x) !is.symbol(x), .)  - this works, but its introduces a lot of clutter. I tried to pull it out into it's own function, but then the wrong environment is collected...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to say here. Maybe you should start a new question? This sounds like a different issue.